# Why hydrogen bond forming has lifetimes on picosecond scale?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, physical-chemistry

According to this Research

http://www.kinetics.nsc.ru/mds/downloads/2009_JSC_Naber_Vol_LifeTime.pdf

hydrogen bonds are formed and destroyed within a timescale of a few picoseconds. Why hydrogen Bonding is such a quick process? Does Fermi's Golden rule give the answer? Or can the timescale be derived by classical mechanics assumption?

Supposing we have a bond with attraction Energy $U_0$ and the potential Minimum of the hydrogen bond is at distance $a$. Let the particle that is attracted in this potential have mass $m$. Assuming that inside the attractive Region of the potential we have harmonic oscillator, we will have energies of order:

$E \propto kx^2 = m \omega^2 x^2$,

where $x$ is displacement from Minimum and $\omega$ the characteristic frequency. We want to know where $E$ is of order $U_0$ as $x$ is of order $a$. Then we have

$\omega \propto \sqrt{\frac{U_0}{a^2m}}$.

Is this a good Approximation for estimating Lifetimes of hydrogen bonds? Or should we use other considerations?